# TortoiseSVN main commit

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Is it possible to commit the same data in multiple branches and update all togehter ?

For example: I want add a Readme.txt file.

this is my file structure where I want add and commit my **Readme.txt**

```
branch\Project1\Readme  
branch\Project2\Readme     
branch\Project3\Tool\Readme
```

If I do later changes on my Readme.txt I want also commit all the Readme.txt in the other Projects.

Is there a way to do this ? How is this procedure called ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for [SVN externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.externals.html). Historically this has only worked with folders, but from Subversion 1.6 onwards you can have individual files as externals.

If you'd like to use TortoiseSVN, there are [some instructions](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-howto-common-projects.html) on their website, but you probably want the [`svn:externals` version](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-externals.html).